# React multiple refs refer to the same element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ref

I am working on a form in React that uses a date picker, which uses a ref. However, when multiple of these date pickers are put onto one form, the refs on each datepicker instance seems to refer to the last one defined on the form. For example, choosing a date on the first or second date picker would only update the last one but not itself.

Where I define the ref:

```
<div className={styles.datePicker} ref={this.setWrapperRef}>
            <div className={styles.mdpInput}  onClick={()=> this.showDatePicker(true)}>
                <input type='date' onChange={this.updateDateFromInput} ref={inputRef}/>
            </div>
            ...rest of code
</div>
```

Setting the ref:

```
setWrapperRef(node){
    this.wrapperRef = node;
}
```

I also made sure to bind the function:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    let date = new Date();
    let year = date.getFullYear();
    let month = date.getMonth();
    this.state = {
        year,
        month,
        selectedDay: todayTimestamp,
        monthDetails: this.getMonthDetails(year, month)
    }

    this.setWrapperRef = this.setWrapperRef.bind(this);
}
```

I just learned about refs and I am fairly new to React, so there might be a simple answer that I am overlooking or unaware of. Thanks!

Comment: Don't keep all of them in a single ref.

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by not keeping them all in the same ref. The code above is its own DatePicker component and I am rendering it on a parent component. The parent component has no refs, only the DatePicker component.